# ADT Plugin installation issues Eclipse 3.7 Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: android, ubuntu, adt

I am trying to install Android SDK and ADT Plugiun for Eclipse 3.7 and Ubuntu 11.10.

1. I have downloaded `android-sdk_r15-linux.tgz` and unpacked it to `/home/user/android-sdk-linux`
2. I navigated to `/home/user/android-sdk-linux/tools` and ran android in the terminal as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) Step 4
3. Then I have downloaded all the Platform and other components.
4. I went in to Eclipse and Help -> Install New Software and added the [site](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) Google Android -  successfully and checked the Developer Tools and when I do that here is what I get:

   > Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
   >   Software being installed: Android Development Tools 15.0.0.v201110251216-213216 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 15.0.0.v201110251216-213216)
   >   Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 15.0.0.v201110251216-213216 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 15.0.0.v201110251216-213216) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

I have installed this before on Ubuntu 10.04 and it worked fine. Am I missing something.

P.S. When I go into Eclipse and go to Window -> Preferences I do not see Android as an option on the left side with other options which confuses me.

Do I need to do something else with the tar.gz file that I downloaded from developer.android.com?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution found on this [site](http://zidalife.spyro.it/?p=635)

simply add repo for Indigo release!

The repo is [here](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem earlier this week.  I did lots of different things, such as uninstalling and reinstalling, added all sorts of other things to the install software section

Try adding this to the Install software.

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo

Comment: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo in my case...thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Go to Eclipse ... choose Help > Check for Updates 
and select any updates for the eclipse platform.... 
Try installing the ADT plugin again... 
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your Eclipse, follow these steps:

1. click on Help
2. Install new software
3. Add the site: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
4. select `"linux tools"`
5. install it
6. Try installing the `ADT` plugin again.