# installing ADT plugin 17

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

Hi I recently Updated my computer so I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 64-bits. to install again My android SDK, I went thorough the:

```
http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing
```

Installation guide. So when I clicked next after selecting development tools, I receive this message

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 17.0.0.v201203161636-291853) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found.
```

That prevents me to follow the next step. I', using Eclipse 3.7 that I downloaded from the ubuntu software center.

if any one knows what could be wrong y would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: make sure that you have the 64 bit version of eclipse and java runtime

Comment: check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106673/adt-plugin-installation-issues-eclipse-3-7-ubuntu-11-10

Comment: Eclipse is 64-bits for sure, on ubuntu software Center the non 64-bits apps like skype have this (i386) after the name. Also, I have ia32-lib installed to run 32-bits applications.

Comment: thanks E-riz I would try the same solution, I didn't find it on my first search

Comment: you are missing org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0 might check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249695/adt-requires-org-eclipse-wst-sse-core-0-0-0-but-it-could-not-be-found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an exact duplicate of another question: [Android ADT Installation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540145/android-adt-installation-error/)

In short, don't use Eclipse that comes from any Linux software repository; download from www.eclipse.org instead.

Answer (score 1):

Actually not, I downloaded from www.eclipse.org and had the same problem.
To fix it, I executed Eclipse as root once and made the ADT installation. Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Problem on Win 7 (64 Bit)
To solve it, run eclipse as administrator!

(I found this thread via Google. If some)

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `.metadata` directory from your workspace.