# Why doesn't Android appear in Eclipses' preferences?

Tags: android, eclipse, development-environment, toolkit

I've installed the Android Developer tools as per the [official instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

[image: Installed apps]

Why doesn't the tab appear in `Windows->Preferences`, as [they said](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#configuring) it should?

[image: Eclipse preferences]

Comment: What is your version of Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse SDK

Version: 3.7.2
Build id: M20120208-0800

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't fix your issue directly, but I suggest your take a look at the MOTODEV STUDIO for Android. Essentially, it's a customized Eclipse IDE with all the Android tools preinstalled and many more of their own tools for app validation. I find their tools usefull, especially the code snippets and the app validator. I believe you will need to register to download, but it's a quick and free process and you can always use a temporary email service. Anyway, this should allow you to get up and running until you find your bug (even if I don't see why you'd switch back to plain eclipse).

[MOTODEV STUDIO for ANDROID](http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevstudio/?utm_campaign=mhp01092012&utm_source=mhp&utm_medium=mws)

Comment: Thanks, I was Googling for something similar earlier today. `+1`

Comment: Accepted as an answer, as I finally got the emulator to work within it.

Answer (score 8):

Remove the plugin, then restart as follows:

**eclipse -clean**

Now try reinstalling the ADT from the online installation

**OR**

Head over to Help -> Install New Software. Click on Available software sites. Delete the Android repo. Uncheck Indigo & Eclipse updates & recheck them. Now head back to Help -> Check for updates. Once done, add the Android repo again. Accept the license & you should be good to go.

Happy Coding..

Comment: I tried with a completely new Eclipse 2 days ago, it did not work. I changed the permissions on that directory to take ownership, and tried again; but it still did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Check your plugins directory, located in the folder you extracted the original eclipse zip file to.

For me it is located in

```
eclipse-java-indigo-SR2-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins
```

and I see the following files related to the ADT plugin

```
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar
com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar
com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar
com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar
overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar
```

Make sure you have files similar to these.

Now open a shell and run the following in your eclipse install directory

```
eclipse.exe -console
```

you should get the `osgi` (Open Services Gateway Initiative) console. Now you can see whether your bundles have unresolved dependencies and start them manually. So try

```
osgi> diag com.android.ide.eclipse.adt
```

and

```
osgi> start com.android.ide.eclipse.adt
```

and check the output.

Comment: Yes, I have all those files. Output: `C:\Program Files\Eclipse3\plugins>ls *android*`
`com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar`
`com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar`
`com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar`
`com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar`
`overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay_18.0.0.v201203301601-306762.jar`

Comment: @AT ok that's a good sign. I updated my answer with something else to try

Comment: Hmm, I think you're onto something. [Here's my output](http://pastie.org/4121749)

Comment: Oh I already had a problem with wst !  This should be relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249695/adt-requires-org-eclipse-wst-sse-core-0-0-0-but-it-could-not-be-found   (Use the instruction for Indigo)

Comment: @AT that looks similar to the problem in this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/6785527/984393 check out the answer I linked and see if installing **WST Server Adapters** gets you the `org.eclipse.wst.xml.*` dependency you need

Comment: Installing the WST Server Adapters gave me [the same errors](http://pastie.org/4124282).

Comment: Hang on a minute... you put Eclipse in `Program Files`? Try extracting it into your `Users/name/Downloads` (otherwise you might have to run it as Administrator) and then install ADT.

Comment: @AT I know you are using something other than Eclipse now, but I am curious what the cause of your problems was

Comment: As am I. The bounty is still up if anyone can give me a working solution.

Comment: @AT so extracting Eclipse to a folder other than Program Files didn't work? See my comment above

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the only thing that could tell me my java version was not the one expected after an update.

Answer (score 2):

Have you restarted eclipse after install of ADT plugin

Comment: Yes, I have restarted the IDE thrice.

Comment: are you getting Android sdk manager and AVD manager inside windows.

Comment: Neither appear in the Windows menu, or if you were talking about my Preferences dialogue see above.

Comment: even if you are not getting AVD manager and sdk manager inside windows in eclipse.means installation is not done properly.I think you should have to do fresh installation with eclipse.

Comment: I started on a clean install of Windows (thus a clean install of Eclipse), and followed the guide to the letter. So redoing this without changes won't make a difference.

Comment: you can follow this pdf..http://www.buzztouch.com/resources/Setting_Up_Your_Android_Development_Environment_v1.3.pdf

Comment: Okay, got up to **8.** on page 18 before it gave me [this (aforementioned) image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/V5M0F.png)

Answer (score 2):

I see you are on Windows, I had the same problem and in my case I had to run Eclipse **as administrator to install the plugin**, so uninstall it, restart eclipse as administrator and reinstall it. You don't need afterward to run eclipse as administrator just to use the plugin, its only required for the installation.

The root cause might be folders ownership problems, as quoted by others, when I had the same problem I tried setting folders ownership but I could not apply my permission changes so running as administrator eclipse was the easy way for me. If you are not allowed to run eclipse as administrator on your station then you should search on the ADT documentation which folder should be owned by the user running Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Check the answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106673/adt-plugin-installation-issues-eclipse-3-7-ubuntu-11-10.):

Maybe going to choose Help > Check for Updates or reinstalling ADT plugin again works.

Comment: It didn't find any updates. My software locations are: http://pastebin.com/PtYX2aEE

Comment: I have no more ideas. Maybe i'd try to have another clean installation of eclipse and installing again the ADT plugin.

Comment: I started on a clean install of Windows (thus a clean install of Eclipse), and followed the guide to the letter. So redoing this without changes won't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

There are chances that the plugin may not have been correctly installed. Try reinstalling the ADT. Or in the help menu check for the updates nad try installing through it.
I hope it 'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which you are using eclipse id , i think you are not using proper id. For better reference visit below links

[Hello-world-example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-hello-world-example/)

[Installing-adt](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I've solved it like these:

- Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software.
- Click Add, in the top-right corner.
- In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the
  Name and the following URL for the Location:
  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- Click OK.
- If you have trouble acquiring the plugin, try using "http" in the
  Location URL, instead of "https" (https is preferred for security
  reasons).
- In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to
  Developer Tools and click Next.
- In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded.
  Click Next. Read and accept the license agreements, then click
  Finish.
- If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or
  validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
- When the installation completes, restart Eclipse.

Followed from [here](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)